# A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, deep-linking, global-key

The issues comes when I try to open the app from deeplink in killed state. It gives me this error :

```
A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list.
The offending GlobalKey was:
[LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorSta te>#53296 Key Created by default]
The parent of the widgets with that key was:
FocusInheritedScope
The first child to get instantiated with that key became:
Navigator- [LabeledGlobalKey<
NavigatorState>#53296 Key
Created by default]
The second child that was to be instantiated with that key was:
_FocusInheritedScope
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
See also: https://flutter. dev/ docs/testing/errors
this is the error i am getting
```

I am just using global key to open the end drawer.

I tried using single global key instance to open the drawer in all 3 screen and also tried using different global keys.

Comment: I'd suggest copying your project and simplifying your code down to the minimal code that reproduces the problem.  Then share some of your code here to get more help.